# Почему для div с классом flex не удается установить border?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, border

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 10px;
    border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="flex">
    <div class="flexbox">Контейнер 1 </div>
    <div class="flexbox">Контейнер 2 </div>
    <div class="flexbox">Контейнер 3 </div>
    <div class="flexbox">Контейнер 4 </div>
</div>

<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы забыли указать `border-style`

Answer (score 1):

Надо указывать не только толщину рамки, но также ее начертание и цвет:

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 10px solid #ccc;
    border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="flex">
    <div class="flexbox">Контейнер 1 </div>
    <div class="flexbox">Контейнер 2 </div>
    <div class="flexbox">Контейнер 3 </div>
    <div class="flexbox">Контейнер 4 </div>
</div>

<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

А если хотите разграничить ячейки, то такую же махинацию надо выполнить для класса flexbox:

```
.flexbox {
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: P.S. цвет можно не указывать, это опциональный параметр, но такая запись используется чаще всего

Comment: P.S. цвет можно не указывать, это опциональный параметр, но такая запись используется чаще всего